# JSP not loading JavaScript files if Servlet used to redirect

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am building my first J2EE application using J2EE 7 and JDK 7. I have a JSP that says:

script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/appName/javascript/MyScript.js">close-tag

If I use the (welcome-file) tag in the web.xml then it loads the page and the JavaScript file. I can see the alert it prints and in firebug under "Net" it shows that it downloads the 226 bytes. If, however, I use a servlet to determine the page it needs to open and use response.sendRedirect() or RequestDispatcher.forward() then firebug has status "200 OK", but it does not download the JavaScript file. It says "0 bytes".

So, basically, if I use the servlet to redirect to pages that import JavaScript files from webapps (tomcat) it does not find them. If I use the web.xml to determine the URL I want and open that in firefox, it finds them.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What's your servlet's context path? If it's the default (root) one, the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` will return empty string and the URL in the src attribute will not start with `/` resulting in relative URL. This may be the reason why the javascript is loaded only from your welcome page and not from your forwarding or redirecting servlet. Open the HTML source code of your page and look, how was the `<javascript>` tag and the `src` attribute rendered.

Comment: The context path is: "http://localhost:8080/myapp/" and I opened the script tag and it says: "/myapp/myapp/javascript/myapp.js". Firebug, however, builds the entire URL with HTTP, localhost, etc. It is the exact same if I use the welcome-file. There is no difference. Inexplicable J2EE..........